# How to save associated model's value changes (association attached via include)?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the two models `User` and `Person` joined with two associations that store in `persons` table `creatorID` and `userID`. When I'm creating a new `user` I'd like to create associated `person` instance with both `userID` and `creatorID` filled with `user`'s `ID` (the fields are separated, because sometimes `person` can be created without userID - that's intended).

I believe it is not possible to merge 2 associations in a way to create single `person` record (including both will create 2 records - prove me wrong please?). I have tried numerous ways that I found mainly on Stockoverflow, but none of them saved changes to the associated model, just to the main model.

My code:

```
models.User.hasOne(models.Person, { foreignKey: 'userID', onDelete: 'SET NULL' });
models.User.hasMany(models.Person, { as: 'creator', foreignKey: 'creatorID', constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });

models.User.create({ name: 'system', person: { name: 'test' } }, { include: [{ model: models.Person, foreignKey: 'userID' }] })
    .then(user => {

        user.name = 'updated name'; // this change gets saved
        user.person.creatorID = user.ID; // this does not
        return user.save();
    })
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
    });
```

I tried 
1) modifying the related property directly:
`user.person.creatorID = userID;`

2) using 'set' method:
`user.set('person', {...})`

3) using `user.updateAttributes(...)` -> results in error 'updateAttributes is not a function'

4) including both models in the `create` function, but this just causes two persons being created (and both have just `personID` filled in still! - I'd expect one created with `personID` and another with `userID`(?!))

In case of options 1 and 2 the object gets changed, but the chnages are not saved. Only changes to the direct properties of parent object itself (e.g. `user.name='new name'`) get saved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, however it took me a while to experiment it out. Save must be called on the associated model instance, not the main model:

```
user.person.save();
```

Nonetheless if someone knows how to create a dually associated instance with both foreign keys filled out at once, I'd appreciate a hint! ;)